# how can i decrease delay in this.time.addEvent in phaser.js, based on score?

Tags: javascript, events, delay, phaser-framework

Someone already asked that question, but they didn't seem to get the right answer.

This is my code:

```
const eggGenLoop = this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 1500 - (gameState.score * 100),

        callback: eggGen,

        callbackScope: this,

        loop: true,
    });
```

so the delay doesn't change, clearly phaser just takes the initial gameState.score which is 0. two months ago i tried to make the same game, using plain JavaScript and setTimeout() / setInterval(), but i stumbled at the same obstacle, i hoped with phaser.js it would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, using `this.time.addEvent` and setting `delay` won't work, the reason is because the `TimerEvent` is created once, on
the call *`this.time.addEvent(...)`*.

I see two *simple* options *(personally I would choose option 2)*:

**Option 1)**
You could instead use `setTimeout` and call it *recursively*, and update the `delay` on each call.

```
   function setTimoutWithVariableDelta( score ){
        setTimeout(
            _ => {
                // ... do some stuff
                setTimoutWithVariableDelta( gameState.score );
            },
            1500 - (score * 100));
    }
```

Depending on your code, this option might not work well *(and btw.: `setTimeout`, doesn't stop when the browser is in the background).*

**Option 2)**
Or you could use the `Scene` `update` function.
I put the logic for this type of dynamic delay into the function `callOnMuliplierInterval`, it should be straight forward. Just using the `time` parameter of the update function to keep track of the delay. *(here the [link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.52.0/focus/Phaser.Scene-update))*

**Here is a possible example:**
*(Sorry it got abit long, I got carried away)*

- Just click the buttons to change the score multiplier.

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 203,
    scene: { create, update },
    banner: false
}; 

let interval = 2000;

let lastRun = -1;
let statusText;
let score = 1;
let currentDelta = 1;
let callsCount = 0;

function create () {
    statusText = this.add.text(220, 20, `Score multiplier: ${score}`)
        .setFontFamily('Arial')
        .setFontStyle('bold')
        .setFontSize('20px');
    
    createButton(this, 40, 20, 0xff0000, '#ffffff', .33);
    createButton(this, 40, 80, 0x0000ff, '#ffffff', .66);
    createButton(this, 40, 140, 0x008800, '#ffffff', 1);
    
}

// demo helper function for creating buttons
function createButton(scene, x, y, color, textColor, multiplier){
    let button = scene.add.rectangle(x, y, 140, 40, color)
        .setOrigin(0);
    let buttonText = scene.add.text(0, 0, `Score: ${multiplier}`)
        .setFontFamily('Arial')
        .setFontStyle('bold')
        .setFontSize('20px');
    
    Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(buttonText, button);
    
    button
        .setInteractive()
        .on('pointerdown',  _ => score = multiplier);
}

// this function contains the important logic
function callOnMuliplierInterval(time){
    let newMessage = `Score multiplier: ${score}\n`; 
     newMessage += `ElapsedTime: ${(time / 1000).toFixed(0)}s\n\n`;
     newMessage += `CurrentDelay: ${currentDelta}\n`;
    newMessage += `NextDelay: ${interval * score}\n\n`;
   
    newMessage += `TimesCalled: ${callsCount}`;

    // Execute on: first Run or when the delay has passed
    if( lastRun == -1 || lastRun + currentDelta <= time ){
        lastRun = time;
        currentDelta = interval * score;
        // HERE YOU WOULD DO THE ACTION
        callsCount++;
    } 
    
    // Just update the message
    statusText.setText(newMessage);
}

function update(time, delta){
   callOnMuliplierInterval(time);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and i can see in your example, that it does what  i'm trying to achieve, i just don't know how to apply it in my code. Where's `time` declared and how would it impact the rest of the code in my `update()` function.

Comment: @chylinski `time` is a default parameter, that is passed to the `update` function of each `scene`, you just have to add the `time` parameter to your `update` function.

Comment: here the [link to the documenation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scene.html#update__anchor), that shows this.